# APIs given as .java, not .jar

Tags: java, eclipse, api, jar, package

I am new to Java and trying to import an API from GitHub, to use its functions in my project. API is on GitHub as Java files, but the only documentation I can find on the web is for Jar files.

I just need to access these functions in my code in Eclipse---what do I do?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to walk through a basic tutorial on how Java works before trying to integrate external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your various options include:

1. Figure out if the jars exist in a maven repository. Typically the project will mention that in their documentation. If so, you can use a package manager like [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_use_external_dependencies) or [gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) to download that jar into your project.
2. If the project does not have jars in a public repository, check the Releases tab in github. It may have jars that the project owners have built.
3. If those are also not there, clone the repo and build the code into a jar yourself. The project would likely have build scripts committed or otherwise docs for how to build it.